# insert print_r output to database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert print_r output into database?

In the database, the result is `1`?

How to solve this problem?

```
<?php
    processLog(print_r($dataArray));

    function processLog($text) {
        global $process, $db, $groupID;

        print($text . "\n");

        $SQL = "INSERT INTO enable_log (process_id, process_date, group_id,  log_output, log_time)
               VALUES(:process_id, :process_date, :group_id, :log_output, now())";

        $q = $db->prepare($SQL);
        $q->bindValue(":process_id", $process['pid']);
        $q->bindValue(":process_date", $process['date']);
        $q->bindValue(":group_id", $groupID);
        $q->bindValue(":log_output", $text);
        $q->execute();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing the output of `print_r()` (which you can do with @xzyfer 's answer), I would suggest using [`serialize()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.serialize.php) so that PHP can reverse the string back into a proper array if you ever need to pull it back out of the database.

```
processLog(serialize($dataArray));
```

Comment: That is a good idea, thanks. Not all the processLog will be an array. Some might be just text.

Answer (score 4):

Pass true as the second parameter to print_r:

```
$a = print_r($var, true);
```

Stores the output of `print_r($var)` to $a;

In your example:

```
$q->bindValue(":log_output", print_r($text, true));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you pass the return param to print_r you can use the result instead of it printing out

`$result = print_r($text, true);`

$result will now contain what would have previously been output.

See the manual [here](https://www.php.net/print_r)