# i cant see my posted data via curl ?

Tags: php, curl, mediawiki

i'm just new in php , curl i wrote a small mediawiki extension that send the recent change . the problem is when is send this data i try to write it in a file but "1" is only what appear i tried to use `var_dump` but no changes my sender code is :

```
$wgHooks['RecentChange_save'][] = 'sendto';
function sendto($recentChange){
    $serialized_data=serialize($recentChange);
    $con=curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $con, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt($con,CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/test.php");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($con,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"data={$serialized_data}");
    $result=curl_exec($con);
    if($result){
        return true ;
    }   
    else 
     return false ;
    curl_close($con);
}
```

and the another code is (which recive):

```
 $a = unserialize($_POST['data']);
 $d=fopen("log.txt","w");
 fwrite($d,print_r($a));//only "1" is written
 fclose($d);
```

i think it's a silly question but i get stuck and need help .

thank you

Comment: For additional enlightenment, [here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610870/insert-print-r-output-to-database) where someone was trying to insert the output of `print_r()` into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
fwrite($d,print_r($a));
```

try

```
fwrite($d,print_r($a, true));
```

By passing `true` as the second argument you instruct [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to capture (i.e. return) the output instead of printing it.

Alternatively, you could use [`var_export($a, true)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead of `print_r()` (for a different representation; I only mention it because you were trying to use `var_dump()` initially).

Comment: that is , it's too simple but what is this true option ?

Comment: print_r by default OUTPUTS to the browser. by passing in the second argument, you tell print_r to RETURN its data otherwise. Your version outputs the 'true' value that print_r returns after its completed OUTPUTTING the dump text.